# Twitterの各ツイートセルのようなTextViewにハッシュタグがあるとボタン化するようなやり方はどのようにやるのでしょうか？

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

以下の画像のようなTwitterの各ツイートセルのようなTextViewにハッシュタグがあるとボタン化するようなやり方はどのようにやるのでしょうか？

ツイート内容をAPIで取得した際には、ただの文字列を`SwiftUI`/`UIKit`で`Button`?に置き換える方法はどのように行うのでしょうか？

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ActiveLabel](https://github.com/optonaut/ActiveLabel.swift)で可能のようです。

ですがSwiftUIで使うには少し工夫が必要のようで、まだうまくいっていません。
それに関しては別の質問として載せました。

[https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/88885/activelabeluikitをswiftuiで使いたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/88885/activelabeluikit%E3%82%92swiftui%E3%81%A7%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)