# ActiveLabel(UIKit)をSwiftUIで使いたい

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

`UIKit`で使える[ActiveLabel](https://github.com/optonaut/ActiveLabel.swift)を`UIViewRepresentable`を使ってSwiftUIで使いたいのですが、各要素(ハッシュタグ, URL, メンション)をタップしても設定したアクションが実行されません。

### 考えられる要素

- サイズがおかしい
- タップ領域がUIKitとSwiftUIで異なる？

```swift
import SwiftUI
import ActiveLabel

struct ActiveText: UIViewRepresentable {
  let text: String
  
  @State var mentionAction: ((String) -> ())?
  @State var hashtagAction: ((String) -> ())?
  @State var urlAction: ((URL) -> ())?

  func onTapMention(_ action: @escaping (String) -> ()) -> ActiveText {
    mentionAction = action
    return self
  }

  func onTapHashtag(_ action: @escaping (String) -> ()) -> ActiveText {
    hashtagAction = action
    return self
  }

  func onTapURL(_ action: @escaping (URL) -> ()) -> ActiveText {
    urlAction = action
    return self
  }

  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ActiveLabel {
    let activeLabel = ActiveLabel()
    activeLabel.text = text
    return activeLabel
  }

  func updateUIView(_ uiView: ActiveLabel, context: Context) {
  }
}
```

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  var text = "https://apple.com #apple @apple"

  var body: some View {
    ActiveText(text: text)
      .onTapMention { mention in
        print("tapped mention \(mention)")
      }
      .onTapURL { url in
        print("tapped url \(url.absoluteString)")
      }
      .onTapHashtag { hashtag in
        print("tapped hashtag \(hashtag)")
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SwiftUIで使えるものを`AttributedText`としてリリースしました。

https://github.com/zunda-pixel/AttributedText

以下の投稿を参考にしました。
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70726761/15098239